# backgroundworker retrieve data from database. timeout expired

Tags: mysql, vb.net, timeout, dataadapter

This is the first time I use background worker. I want to retrieve data around 20.000 rows, save it on dataadapter and showing in on a datagridview

it seems running but then message `Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding` comes up.

What I have done is put : `Connect Timeout=90000` on the connection string and `da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 2000000`, which doesn't seems to have a better end result by make adding few extra zeroes. :(
Here is what I have done. What should I do to make it works. thank you

```
Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter
Dim resultDataTable As DataTable
Dim queryString As String

Private Sub BTNrefresh_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNrefresh.Click
    queryString =" LONG QUERY "
    bw.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork
    MethodGlobal.mySqlCon.Open()

    da = New MySqlDataAdapter(queryString, MethodGlobal.mySqlCon)
    myDataTable = New DataTable

    da.Fill(myDataTable)
    da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 2000000
    Me.DGVtest.DataSource = resultDataTable 
End Sub

Private Sub backgroundworker_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MethodGlobal.NewMysqlConnection("connection")
End Sub
```

Comment: The timeout has to do with the connection to the DB (and thus writing the .ComandTimeout bit AFTER the connection is performed does not make too much sense), not with the BGW. I will better update your tags such that you can get help quickly.

Comment: varocarbas. i moved the commandtimeout = 2000000 and moved it to after da = new mysqldataadapter. Then it gave me    "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ProgressBar1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."  I read on msdn "You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events."   So, I moved dgvdatasource to bw_runworkercompleted, and it works! thanks. :)

Comment: You are welcome (although you were the one finally solving it). This last error was effectively related to BGW. It is not too clear why was exactly triggered just by looking at your code; but the important parts are there: timeout is related to the db and thus has to be set before connecting to the db; and you cannot affect GUI controls from the BGW thread. Happy that you solved you problem and shared the process with future readers.